# unexpected eval in _generate_background_page.html Chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that I've written in TypeScript and React+JSX. I'm seeing the following error in the Chrome extensions tab for my extension:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Context
_generated_background_page.html
Stack Trace
js/background.js:291 (anonymous function)
```

I am not using `eval` anywhere in my code. Because extensions now ask for a CSP, I am using a CSP which excludes `eval` (this is considered a best practice). I thought that TypeScript might be compiling my code, or the JSX code, to use `eval`. However, I cannot find `eval` anywhere in the minified/compiled code. Do you all have any idea what this might refer to?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `webpack` uses `eval` when the devtool option is specified. More documentation can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/). This fact becomes more visible when building in development (unminified) mode.

This behaviour is unfortunate.